# list of tensors into tensors

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a list like

```
xs = [tensor1, tensor2, tensor3....]
```

I want to change it into a tensor so that I can feed xs and ys into the Pytorch DataLoader.
I tried this,

```
xs = torch.Tensor(xs)
```

but it doesn't work as the individual elements are not items but tensors.

Comment: Do the tensors have the same dimensionality (this might not necessarily be given if the task is NLP or time series-related)?

Comment: @dennlinger Yes, dimensionality is the same. the tensor is an image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want [`torch.stack`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.stack)

```py
xs = torch.stack(xs)
```